# Can't pass in variable to requestPermissions()

Tags: android, kotlin

My activity `RequiresLocation` is to request permission to location services.

Here's the code:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_requires_location.*
import java.util.jar.Manifest

class RequiresLocation : AppCompatActivity() {

    val requestCode: Int = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_requires_location)

        turnOnLocationButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission has already been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
                else {
                    requestLocationPermission()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission(): {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            RequiresLocation.class,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    requestCode) // coming up in red
    }
```

however the **requestcode** is coming up in red on Android Studio as unresolved reference. How come I can't pass it in? - is it because it's a private variable?

I'm following the [official android tutorial for `requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#make-the-request)

Comment: Make your `requestCode` variable constant i.e.`const val requestCode: Int = 1` in **companion object** and use instance of your activity like `this@RequiresLocation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`this@RequiresLocation`** instead of **`RequiresLocation.class`**

Try this

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this@RequiresLocation,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    requestCode)
```

Or

```
private fun requestLocationPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            requestCode) // coming up in red
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
class RequiresLocation : AppCompatActivity() {

    val requestCode: Int = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_requires_location)

        turnOnLocationButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission has already been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else {
                requestLocationPermission()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                requestCode) // coming up in red
    }
}
```

Comment: `this@RequiresLocation` comes up in red, and the 2nd code block `this` is red as well. Any idea?

Comment: Here are the errors for both examples: https://i.imgur.com/crZZ4P2.png, https://i.imgur.com/XReQppa.png

Comment: Thanks that worked - was the problem that a private functions can't live outside of the class {}?